# C++ socket server doesn't accept any clients / client won't connect

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, winsockets

I have a simple class that starts a server and listens to clients and after they connect it starts a thread for them, my problem is that when I run the server it seems to be listening and when I try to connect using simple python code the server doesn't accept a socket.

Obviously I thought the problem is with the client connection but after trying to change to address from loopback to my local address I get the same result so I'm not sure what's causing this.

Server code:

```cpp
Communicator::Communicator()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to startup WSA");
    }

    m_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (m_sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create socket");
    }
}


Communicator::~Communicator()
{
    try
    {
        WSACleanup();
        closesocket(m_sock);
    }
    catch (...) {}
}

void Communicator::bindAndListen()
{
    SOCKADDR_IN sa;
    sa.sin_port = Config::getConfig()["port"]; // 8080
    sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sa.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (bind(m_sock, (const SOCKADDR*) & sa, sizeof(sa)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to bind socket");
    }

    if (listen(m_sock, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to start listening");
    }

    std::cout << "Listening" << std::endl; // This gets printed
    while (true)
    {
        SOCKET clientSock = accept(m_sock, NULL, NULL); // Nothing accepted, program stuck here
        std::cout << "Connection" << std::endl;
        if(clientSock == INVALID_SOCKET)
        { 
            throw std::runtime_error("Invalid connection");
        }

        startThreadForNewClient(clientSock);

    }

}
```

Testing python code:

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8080))
s.send(b"h")
```

The only error I'm getting is `[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it` on my client, the server is continuously listening.

Comment: Show the code of this function `Config::getConfig()["port"]` maybe `htons` is missing?

Comment: Yep, that was the problem, I forgot to put it in `htons`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that I forgot to put the port in `htons`, sorry for my rookie mistake.

```cpp
void Communicator::bindAndListen()
{
    SOCKADDR_IN sa;
    sa.sin_port = htons(Config::getConfig()["port"]); 
    sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sa.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (bind(m_sock, (const SOCKADDR*) & sa, sizeof(sa)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to bind socket");
    }

    if (listen(m_sock, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to start listening");
    }

    std::cout << "Listening" << std::endl;
    while (true)
    {
        SOCKET clientSock = accept(m_sock, NULL, NULL);
        std::cout << "Connection" << std::endl;
        if(clientSock == INVALID_SOCKET)
        { 
            throw std::runtime_error("Invalid connection");
        }

        startThreadForNewClient(clientSock);

    }

}
```

Comment: In your defense, requiring the calling code to remember to use `htons()` is a pretty ugly design flaw in the BSD sockets API.  The nativeEndian->bigEndian transformation could have just as easily been handled implicitly inside the `bind()` function itself, saving countless programmer-hours' worth of head-scratching.